# The use 'revenge' in "The poor murdered girl must be revenged."

Tags: word-usage

> The poor murdered girl must be revenged.

I saw the sentence in the dictionary on my cellphone. I doubt the use of 'revenged' in that sentence and I think it should use 'avenged' instead because, as I know, 'revenge' can't take a direct object (as in "she vowed to revenge her brother's death."). But I might be wrong. Any thoughts?

Edit:

The reason why I was confused is that I found [this Grammar Point in Oxford dictionary.](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/avenge)

> **Grammar Point**
>
> **avenge / revenge**
>
> Avenge is a verb; revenge is (usually) a noun.
>
> People avenge something or avenge themselves on somebody:She vowed to
>   avenge
>   her brother’s death. He later avenged himself on his wife’s killers.
>   You take revenge on a person.
>
> In more formal or literary English, revenge can also be a verb. People
>   revenge themselves on somebody or
>   are revenged on them (with the same meaning):He was later revenged on
>   his wife’s killers. You cannot revenge something: *She vowed to revenge
>   her brother’s death*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usage is correct. Granted, "revenge" is the lesser used verb among the two.

[The Oxford Dictionaries Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/revenge) considers the verb form literary:

> Inflict revenge on behalf of (someone else)
>
> *‘it's a pity he chose that way to revenge his sister’*

It should be noted that "revenge" tends to mean, but not always, seeking retribution for oneself whereas "avenge" is about seeking justice on behalf of others.

Comment: So, the sentence "*she vowed to revenge her brother's death.*" is also correct?

Comment: @dan It sure is. Funny you should ask, the next example on ODO is _‘her brother was slain, and she revenged his death’_

Comment: Interesting, the Oxford dictionary on my phone says the sentence "*she vowed to revenge her brother's death.*" is wrong. That's why I'm confused.

Comment: @dan This usage is considered somewhat dated. Check out [Google Books examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22revenged+his+death%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIgpm5pv_hAhXPVN8KHUPODVcQ_AUIFCgB) and [this](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=9yvMXNyUNfKI_QbGmamoBw&q=%22revenged+her+death%22&oq=%22revenged+her+death%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...60069.60805.0.60930.4.4.0.0.0.0.115.331.3j1.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.EtW71j1d60M). Most of them are over 100 years old. But some contemporary writers use it too.

Comment: I found this in Oxford dictionary: "**People avenge something or avenge themselves on somebody:She vowed to avenge her brother’s death. He later avenged himself on his wife’s killers. You take revenge on a person.
In more formal or literary English, revenge can also be a verb. People revenge themselves on somebody or are revenged on them (with the same meaning):He was later revenged on his wife’s killers. You cannot revenge something:She vowed to revenge her brother’s death.**" https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/avenge